# The type 'Window' does not support direct content

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have a WPF solution built with VS 2015 composed of several projects.  Suddenly I started receiving a warning in design mode stating the following:

> The type 'Window' does not support direct content.

I understand how some controls do not support direct content, but `System.Windows.Window` should.  I get the same warning with `UserControl`, and as far as I know, any other control that typically supports direct content.

Everything compiles and runs fine, but having the blue underlines through all of my XAML is bothersome.  Has anyone else come across this?

Below is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try a clean, then rebuild all.

Comment: @user2946329 - The reasoning for using an image instead of text is to demonstrate the blue underlining running rampant throughout my XAML code.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer  - Thanks, but I tried that already.

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue?

Comment: Like you, I just started having this problem out of nowhere.  Restarting Visual Studio seems to make it go away.  Trying to figure out what triggers it to start happening...extremely annoying and frustrating issue.

Comment: It can also happen if you added the window in a class library project and don't have the system.xaml reference.

Comment: I updated to  Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and seems to have resolved the probelm

Comment: I Clean and Reuild the solution and the problem solved, quite strange. I haven't installed Update yet

Comment: Clean and rebuild solves it. I'm using VS 2015 Update 1.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Make sure you reference System.Xaml. Clean and rebuild the project. Works on VS 2015 Update 1.

Comment: This was the solution for me (after a get latest from TFS).  I don't know why that reference turned up missing!

Comment: Don't forget to **Clean**. I didn't clean it first, then it didn't work.

Comment: +1. PS: if you get error messages like "'Binding' does not derive from MarkupExtension" or "x:Type does not exist in namespace ...", removing and re-adding the references to PresentationCore, PresentationFramework and WindowsBase seems to help.

Comment: If you "Clean" you can just "Build".

Answer (score 32):

At least in a WPF IronPython project, adding the `System.Xaml` reference to the project solved the problem for me:

[image]

An important thing to note here is that adding seemingly *any* reference will make the problem go away *temporarily* -- until Visual Studio is restarted. `System.Xaml`, on the other hand, appears to keep the problem at bay. I even tried removing the reference, whereafter the problem returned upon restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Comment: @MeerDeen Some people in the comments said that Clean and Rebuild resolved the issue for them. I might also suggest removing and re-adding this reference.

Comment: You should consider closing and reopen solution. If even this does not solve it, restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

For me this error was happening because I added a WPF Window to a class library project.

For some reason (unknown by me), Visual Studio doesn't give us the option to select the **WPF Window** template from the "**Add New Item...**" dialog box if the project was not created as a **WPF Application**. Instead, it only offers the option to add a **WPF User Control**. Because of that, I selected the **User Control** template for the new item, and then edited the source code to make the XAML to become a **Window** object rather than a **User Control**.

```
<!-- The new item was created as an UserControl, but what I needed was a Window object. -->
<UserControl>
   ...
</UserControl>

<!-- Changed it to Window and made other necessary adjustments. -->
<Window>
   ...
</Window>
```

The problem was actually in the code-behind. Since it was created as an **User Control**, the window partial class was inheriting from **UserControl**, like the following:

```
public partial class MyWindow : UserControl
{
    public MyWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

To fix it I just had to remove the inheritance, making my window class inherith from nothing, like this:

```
public partial class MyWindow
{
    public MyWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

After removing the inheritance, Visual Studio didn't show the error "The type 'Window' does not support direct content." anymore.

Comment: You can (as I did) edit the *.vstemplate:  `<ShowByDefault>true</ShowByDefault>` run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates`, I believe this cleanes the cached templates... restart VS et viola :)

Answer (score 3):

on behalf of @mark Richman I edited the Itemtemplate to automatically Reference "System.Xaml".
Just in case some is interested:

[image]

can be found in: "[VS InstallDir]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\WPF\[InputLocale]\WPFWindow"

BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Add **System.Xaml** and **UIAutomationProvider** references to your project, after that clear solution and then build again

Answer (score 0):

in Visual studio 2019 :
I searched for ( System.Xaml.dll )
and I added it as a reference
its worked well

found it in this location:
" C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.8 "