# WPF control in VSTO add-in - ElementHost vs. native WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, vsto

I have a VSTO Microsoft Word add-in.  When the user clicks a ribbon button, I want a WPF window to show up.  I had always thought the only way to do this was by adding an ElementHost control into a Winforms form and adding WPF controls on top.  But I discovered via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175136/2744914) that I can also do the same thing by converting a WPF UserControl into a WPF Window and using control.Show() to display it.  This seems to obviate the need for using ElementHost.  Before I go down this path, any reason I shouldn't do this?  Is there any technical difference or speed difference in doing it this way?

Comment: Can you confirm that you wish to display a `WPF` window separate from Word and not a Task Pane built with `WPF`?

Comment: @Stephen, definitely not a task pane. Separate window invoked from a button on a custom VSTO ribbon.

Comment: have you seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419089/launching-wpf-windows-from-an-office-add-in

Comment: @Atmane, I hadn't seen that thread...it is interesting but it seems more about launching an entire app rather than just a window/form within an existing add-in.

Comment: Thanks. This is something that I do in a current app, I've had no issues in terms of technical problems or speed. The only thing you'll have to remember is to invoke it on it's own thread and then clean up the `Dispatcher` when the window closes. Apart from this it'll act basically like a normal WPF Window.