# How can I show a WPF window in a VSTO add-in?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, vsto

I am migrating my VBA code to VSTO for the first time to create a COM add-in for excel. I was able to convert all the code to vb. Unfortunately, I have difficulties in creating Windows form in VS2017. I tried to add windows form but I do not see any Windows form. Instead I could add only User Control (WPF).

I did manage to create the form using the XAML but the biggest issue I have is how to initialise the form.

The imports are the ones below

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

I see the following erros in the code below

Handles MyBase.Load --> Event "Load" cannot be found

I do not see anything working after this. Can someone explain me how we deal with loading and unloading the User Control (WPF). Also why I am not able to import windows form.

```
Private Sub UserControl1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim RefSht As Object
    Dim TableList() As String
    Dim IDTable As String
    Dim count As Integer : count = 0
    Dim TextBox1 As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    Dim TextBox2 As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    Dim TextBox3 As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    Dim TextBox4 As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    Dim TextBox5 As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    Dim TextBox6 As System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
    Dim cmbIDTable As System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
    RefSht = wb.Worksheets("RefSheet")

    On Error Resume Next
    IDTable = ReportSheet.Range("IDTable")
    TextBox1.Text = ReportSheet.Range("Title")
    TextBox2.Text = ReportSheet.Range("Component")
    TextBox3.Text = ReportSheet.Range("Selection")
    TextBox4.Text = ReportSheet.Range("Parameters")
    TextBox5.Text = ReportSheet.Range("Summary")
    TextBox6.Text = ReportSheet.Range("Category")

    TableList = Split(GetTableListData(), ";")
    cmbIDTable.ItemsSource = TableList
    While IDTable <> TableList(count)
        count = count + 1
    End While
    cmbIDTable.SelectedItem = count
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you try to create a Windows form? Do you want to add a form to your project (as you would a VBA UserForm) or create one on-the-fly, at run-time? And a Windows Form or WPF - they're not the same.

Comment: @CindyMeister I want the form to stay on the background and appear on clicking the ribbon button. As I am new to WPF, I prefer to explore WPF. Any ideas.

Comment: I highly recommend you do NOT use `On Error Resume Next`, especially not when things "aren't working". Bad habit. In .NET you should use Try...Catch blocks.

Comment: I believe you'll find an answer to your basic question: How can I show a WPF window in a VSTO add-in - in this SO Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164140/open-wpf-form-from-a-vsto-outlook-addin. You may also find the following useful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/08/15/wpf-in-vsto/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772076.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubles running behind the issue, I have discovered that Windows Form was not installed in my VS. I have included the package and I am now able to work.